Error: read ECONNRESET with ASP.NET Core Web API on a Docker container
I'm running .NET 8 and have the below Docker Compose and dockerfile files to deploy my API to Docker from Rider for development.
The API is reachable when I run the API with Kestrel server, however, when I deploy to Docker I get

Error: read ECONNRESET

when I attempt to call the API.
The API can reach the Postgres container as I see the EF migrations running in the Rider console and I am also able to connect to Postgres from Postico via localhost:5432.
I'm thinking it must be some .NET configurations I am missing, but I have searched Google and SO without any luck.
I'm accessing the API with the following URL: http://localhost:5068
Docker Compose:
services:
  
  sweetnotes.api:
    image: esausilva/sweetnotes.api
    container_name: SweetNotes.Api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Api/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5068
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=5068
    ports:
      - "5068:5068"
    depends_on:
      - sweetnotes.db
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ~/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
        
  sweetnotes.db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: SweetNotes.Db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=[USER]
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[PASSWORD]
      - POSTGRES_DB=SweetNotes
    volumes:
      - ./.containers/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5068

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Development
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Api/Api.csproj", "src/Api/"]
COPY ["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Data/Data.csproj", "src/Data/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]

appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SweetNotes": "Server=sweetnotes.db;Port=5432;Database=SweetNotes;User Id=[USER];Password=[PASSWORD];"
  },
  "urls": "http://localhost:5068",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
    }
  },
  "CorsSettings": {
    "FrontendOrigin": "http://localhost:3050"
  }
}

This command is what Rider is running
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /Users/[...]/docker-compose.yml -f /Users/[...]/.idea/.idea.SweetNotesApi/Docker/docker-compose.generated.override.yml -p sweetnotesapi up --force-recreate -d

And this is Rider override
# This is a generated file. Not intended for manual editing.
services:
  sweetnotes.api:
    build:
      context: "/Users/[...]/SweetNotesApi"
      dockerfile: "src/Api/Dockerfile"
      target: "base"
      args:
        BUILD_CONFIGURATION: "Debug"
    command: []
    entrypoint:
    - "/opt/rider-debugger/linux-x64/dotnet/dotnet"
    - "/opt/rider-debugger/JetBrains.Debugger.Worker.exe"
    - "--mode=server"
    - "--frontend-port=57100"
    - "--backend-port=57300"
    - "--timeout=60"
    environment:
      DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER: "true"
      RIDER_DEBUGGER_LOG_DIR: "/var/opt/rider-debugger"
      RESHARPER_LOG_CONF: "/etc/opt/rider-debugger/backend-log.xml"
    image: "esausilva/sweetnotes.api:dev"
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:57019:57100"
    - "127.0.0.1:57219:57300"
    volumes:
    - "/Users/[...]/usersecrets"
    - "/Users/[...]/packages"
    - "/Users/[...]/app:rw"
    - "/Users/[...]/src:rw"
    - "/Users/[...]/rider-debugger"
    - "/Applications/[...]/backend-log.xml"
    - "/Users/[...]/rider-debugger:rw"
    working_dir: "/app"

I'm on MacOS.
Any help is appreciated!

Can you check the logs on the API container to see what interface and port it listens on? Your appsettings has the URL http://localhost:5068 which would cause it to bind to the loopback interface and only accept connections from inside the container. But your environment variables should override that, so it should work.

I'd try the to a) connect to the sweetnotes.api container via shell and curl the API inside the container or b) switch back to the default port 8080 (to isolate the issue)

@HansKilian Hey thanks, I moved "urls": "http://localhost:5068", from appsettings.json to launchSettings.json and now the API works as expected when running in Docker and non-Docker Kestrel. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it as correct. Thanks

I solved my issue by moving "urls": "http://localhost:5068", from appsettings.json to launchSettings.json and now the API works as expected when running in Docker and non-Docker Kestrel.
